# How to have a live data from localStorage with javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, shopping-cart

I have a cart list of customer shopping
I save customer items with add to basket button to localStorage

I have 2 problems

- First one my data of basket in page is old and need to updated without refresh page
- Second in a quick show of my basket at the top repeat the old data with add to basket button every time

Its quick view of the basket

```js
function quickCartShow() {
    let basketNumber = document.getElementById("card-value-numbers");
    let cartItemsList = $("#cart-item-list");
    let quickCart;
    let price = 0;
    basketNumber.innerText = cartItems ? cartItems.length : 0 ;
    cartItems && cartItems.map(item => {
        quickCart =
            `<div class="row m-0 border-bottom mb-1"><div class="col-4 p-0 pl-1 align-self-center"> <a class="w-100" href="#` +
            item.product.url +
            `"> <img draggable="false" class="w-100" src="#` +
            item.product.mainpic +
            `" alt="product img"></a></div><div class="col-8 p-0"><div><a class="w-100 text-muted cart-text" href="#` +
            item.product.url +
            `"><p>` +
            item.product.title +
            `</p></a></div> <div class="d-flex justify-content-between"><p class="text-muted"> ` +
            item.quantity +
            // TODO: Active delete part here
            `  عدد </p><a class="pl-3 text-muted del-btn" onclick="removeFromCartHandler(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div> </div></div>`;
            let advancePrice;
            if (item.length) {
                advancePrice = item.quantity * item.length
                item.product.advance_prices.map(adPrice =>{
                    advancePrice <= adPrice.max ? price += advancePrice * adPrice.vprice : price +=0
                })
            } else {
                item.product.offtype == 0 ? price += (item.quantity * item.product.price) :
                item.product.offtype == 1 ? price += (item.quantity * (((100-item.product.off)/100)*item.product.price)) :
                item.product.offtype == 2 ? price += ((item.quantity * item.product.price) - item.product.off) : price+= 0;
            }
        $("#cart-value-price").text(numberWithCommas(price));
        cartItemsList.append(quickCart);
    });
}
```

and the basket part code is:

```js
function cardItemsShow() {
    let cartContainer = $('.cart-items-page');
    let questPrice = $('#guest-prices');
    let cartItemShow;
    let price = 0;
    let cartsItemParent = $('.cart-items-page');
            cartsItemParent.find("tr").remove();

    cartItems && cartItems.map((item,i) => {
    var maxProduct = ((item.product.max && ( item.product.instock != 2 || (item.product.max < item.product.stock)))) ?
        item.product.max : item.product.instock == 2 ? item.product.stock : null
        console.log(item)
        cartItemShow = 
        `<tr class="class='col-12 checkout-item">`+
            `<td>`+
                `<a href="#` 
                + item.product.url +
                `">` +
                `<img draggable="false" src="#` + 
                 item.product.mainpic +
                `" alt"`
                + item.product.title +
                `">` +
                `</a>` +
            `</td>` +
            `<td class="text-right">`+
            `<a class="text-muted" style="display: inline-block" href="#` + item.product.url +
                `">` + item.product.title +
            `</a></td>` +
            `<td>
                <span style="white-space: nowrap"> `
                    +  
                    ((item.length !== null) ?  item.length + ' سانتی متر '
                        : '')
                    +                    
                `</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                        <form class="`+item.id+ ` onsubmit="return false" >
                        <p class="mb-0">تعداد</p>
                        <div class="number-input">
                            <button
                                onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown(); $('#refresh-btn`+i+`').removeClass('d-none')" type="button"></button>
                            <input class="quantity number-picker" min="0" name="quantity" id="quantity" max="`+ maxProduct +`"
                                value="`+ item.quantity+`" type="number">
                            <button
                                onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp(); $('#refresh-btn`+i+`').removeClass('d-none')"
                                class="plus" type="button"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pt-1">
                        <a class="btn btn-success refresh-btn d-none" id="refresh-btn`+i+`" href="#" onclick="updateCartShow()" >
                        <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
                        <span> به‌روزرسانی</span>
                        <a/>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td><spam>` +
            numberWithCommas(item.product.price)
            +
            `
             تومان
            </spam>
             </td>
             <td>
             <button onclick="removeFromCartHandler()" class="checkout-btn-remove remove-cart"> × </button>
             </td>
            </tr>  `

    cartContainer.append(cartItemShow)
    let advancePrice;
    if (item.length) {
        advancePrice = item.quantity * item.length
        item.product.advance_prices.map(adPrice =>{
            advancePrice <= adPrice.max ? price += advancePrice * adPrice.vprice : price +=0
        })
    } else {
        item.product.offtype == 0 ? price += (item.quantity * item.product.price) :
        item.product.offtype == 1 ? price += (item.quantity * (((100 - item.product.off)/100)*item.product.price)) :
        item.product.offtype == 2 ? price += ((item.quantity * item.product.price) - item.product.off) : price+= 0;
    }
    questPrice.text(numberWithCommas(price))
    })
}

function updateCartShow() {
   
    cardItemsShow();
    quickCartShow();
}

updateCartShow()

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", event => {
    if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
        updateCartShow();
    }
});

$(document).on("click", ".add-to-basket", function() {
    console.log("aaaa");
    updateCartShow();
});


});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi! I formatted the code as JavaScript for you. Are you getting a syntax error in the browser console? Noticed there is an extra `});` at the end of the code. Your code does not use `localStorage` - that would be the most important part to copy for us : )

Comment: @PeterKrebs I *think* OP is asking how to add `localStorage` to what they're already doing. It's not really clear.